# Уничтожилась сцена в Unity после STOP-ошибки Windows

Tags: windows, unity3d, файлы

Во время работы в Unity3d произошёл сбой системы. После перезагрузки компьютера я открыл проект и обнаружил, что сцена, над которой я работал, пуста. 
У меня нет точек восстановления Windows, и папка Temp в проекте после открытия юнити перезаписалась.
Над игрой я работал уже больше года, и устроена она была таким образом, что практически весь геймплей находился в одной сцене.
Есть ли способ вернуть утраченное?

Comment: если ваш временный файл ("EditModeScene" вроде ) не был повторно создан, то можно его попробовать восстановить какой-нибудь программой для восстановления файлов (а-ля file recovery) и переименовать потом нормально

Comment: За весь год не было бекапов?

Comment: «Люди делятся на две категории: кто еще не делает бэкапы, и кто их уже делает».

Comment: есть бэкап 4-х месячной давности, но это тоже такой себе вариант

Comment: самое время почитать про использование систем контроля версий

Answer (score 1):

Учись на своих ошибках.

Юзай git.
Будет проще если будешь использовать вместе с ним Source Tree вместо консоли.

Репозитории можно хранить на гитХабе или битбаклете и подобных проблем больше не будет.

Так же, как и говорилось выше -- пробуй возобновить временный файл сцены.